# Check (and fix) OpenVPN status over Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, openvpn

We're having problems with one server that doesn't seem to be accessible through VPN.

When I RDP to the server (local network, no VPN needed), the Open VPN icon is red. This on its own is not a problem, since we have other servers having a red icon as well, which are accessible through VPN.

Can I remotely log in to the (problem) server, and try to reconnect with the OpenVPN GUI like that?

Also, the server does have a "connected" state on the VPN network adapter, but it cannot ping the gateway or be pinged itself. What should I be looking for in the log files that might tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was routes not being added properly. Restarting the vpn service (temporarily) fixed the problem.